# Entity framework throwing invalid operation exception - Connection string in app.config not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I added a new ADO.NET data model from the database, and everything generated fine.

Then I try to make a call to get one of the tables:

```
public Sensor[] GetAllRegisteredSensors()
        {
            using (var context = new ClientSensorLocationEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    return context.Sensors.ToArray();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

and I get an exception:

> No connection string named 'ClientSensorLocationEntities' could be
>   found in the application config file.

Pretty self-explanatory and then I went to my `app.config` file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ClientSensorLocationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ClientSensorLocationModel.csdl|res://*/ClientSensorLocationModel.ssdl|res://*/ClientSensorLocationModel.msl;
               provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYUSER\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=ClientSensorLocation;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
               providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
              </connectionStrings>
              <startup>
                <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
          </startup>
        </configuration>
```

So the connection string with that name exists. What seems to be the problem then?

Comment: From what I know, if you are instantiating dbcontext from referencing class libraries or projects, you may need to have the connection string registered in its configuration file also. For example, if you are instantiating it on a web project, check if the connection string is in the web.config

Comment: Yes that's it. My WPF project instantiated a middle layer project's class which then referenced the class with the presented code which was in another project. I had to add connection string to all the projects in chain to get it to work. Care to provide answer so I can accept it?

Comment: That should be fine... your connection string does contain `&quot;`, that should be replaced with quotes... that could be it?

Comment: Hi, glad it helped, I've posted my comment as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `DbContext` from referencing Projects, you also need to register the connection string on the project configuration file.

For example, if you are using the `DbContext` on a web project, check if the connection string is on the web.config.

Comment: You are spot on, the connection string should be in present in the app.config for class libraries and the web.config for web projects.